# Test DOM methods in javascript IDE not in browser console

Tags: javascript, dom, console, ide

I am wondering why when using any IDE that support javascript language if you try to get element of `HTML` page using `document.querySelectorAll()` or any DOM selector method it will return run time error `ReferenceError: document is not defined` ?

is the reason that `document` only defined in browser javascript build in console ?

my problem that I only need to run javascript app on my IDE not on browser console to test it.

if there is any suggested solution please mention it.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by run "on my IDE" ?

I think you rather talking about rendering on server side.

Either way, yeah the document exist solely on the browser, if nothing is done to mock it. but there are solutions to mock the document, for example, `jsdom` :

https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom

It is useful for example for running unit tests on server side, without browser, to test UI components which require DOM and have some logic.

Comment: exactly I want to run my javascript code only on IDE and I am trying to get element of html page using DOM methods but i am always getting `ReferenceError: document is not defined` i think document is not defined on backend IDE for javascript.

Comment: which IDE r u using?

Comment: it's depend on the programming language you are using rather than the IDE. Nodejs will be able to run JS on your PC without browser for example, but still document will not be available without having the solution I said in my answer. netbeans itself doesn't run javascript without browser as far as i know.

Comment: I installed nodejs and link it to neatbeans IDE

Comment: So u must also use some library like `jsdom` in order to get document to be available without browser.

Comment: is there another javascript IDE that work without browser, I think sublime has plugin for nodejs console but I didn't know if it work.

Comment: `const dom = new JSDOM(`<!DOCTYPE html><p>Hello world</p>`);
console.log(dom.window.document.querySelector("p").textContent);`

in your answer i should parse my html page to `JSDOM` constructor in order to work.

Answer (score 0):

Finally solution that worked in my case using `Nodejs`,`jQuery` and `jsdom` library as suggested in [jony89's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43724983/5169186).

in newer `jsdom v10` API I should parse my `HTML` page into `JSDOM` constructor to get the result that I expected.

but it's difficult and inconvenient to pass the whole HTML page to `JSDOM` constructor so I used another simpler way to solve it using older jsdom API and exactly by `jsdom.env()` method :

https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom/blob/master/lib/old-api.md

I pass the page url that I want to use DOM methods on it and then print the output on my nodejs IDE:

```
var jsdom = require("jsdom/lib/old-api.js");

jsdom.env(
    "http://www.ammanu.edu.jo/English/Research/Research.aspx",
    ["http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"],
    function (err, window) {
        var $ =  window.$;
        var a = $("section a");
        for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
           console.log(a[i].getAttribute("href"));
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: @jony89  thanks alot for solution info. it help me much.